# Python CGI - How can I get uploaded file in TCP server?

Tags: python, upload, cgi, multipart

I made TCP server like this

```
serverPort = 8181
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(5)
```

and I can receive user's login data like this

```
elif path == '/login':
        header, query = message.split(b'\r\n\r\n')
        fp = io.BytesIO(query)
        form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp, environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST'})

        connectionSocket.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n')
        connectionSocket.send(b'Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
        connectionSocket.send('<p>Hello {}!</p>'.format(form.getvalue('id')).encode('utf-8'))
```

but I can't receive multipart upload data!!T^T

I wrote HTML for upload file

```
<HTML>
<BODY>

<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="http://127.0.0.1:8181/upload" METHOD=POST>
    File to process: <INPUT NAME="file" TYPE="file">
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send File">
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

how can I receive file and save that?

I know about using HTTP server is good way for this problem

but I shoud using TCP server like that...

please help me! i cant solve this problem...T^T

Comment: read to docs to cgi.FieldStorage

Comment: Why go through all this pain when there is Flask or Pyramid, is what I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File uploads use a different content type; normally a POST uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but a file upload requires the form to use `multipart/form-data`.

The `cgi.FieldStorage` class will normally sniff this from the CGI environment variables, but you are not using CGI here, you are parsing everything at the lowest level. You'll have to pass in a `CONTENT_TYPE` header here:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp, environ={
    'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'multipart/form-data'})
```

Ideally, that header is parsed from the incoming headers, of course.

Comment: Thanks! I did your answer, but error is occurred.. and I wrote my full source code another question ! Can you help me again? link is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723830/python-cgi-upload-error)